# Silverlight - VisualStateManager

Tags: silverlight

I'm playing around with the VisualStateManager and I have a couple of questions.

1. Is it possible to determine the visual state that a Control is in through the VisualStateManager? If so, how?
2. Is there a way to programmatically access a "part" of a control? If so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Out of the box it's not possible. With some work it is possible. VSM supports the concept of a custom VSM. So you can extend VSM to keep track of current state and then attach this custom VSM to to the elements whose state you need to track.

[CustomVisualStateManger docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.customvisualstatemanager(VS.95).aspx)

2. If you know the name of the part you can call [GetTemplateChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.gettemplatechild(VS.95).aspx)